# How to add a placeholder field to Entity Forms

Tags: forms, entities

I am trying to add a placeholder field, but I seem to only be able to add a text field above the form input,

Is it possible to add through the manage fields section in entity form ?

Comment: What's a placeholder field? Do you mean you're trying to add a placeholder attribute to a text field or is "placeholder field" something in Entity Forms maybe?

Answer (score 4):

You should use  [Field placeholder](https://drupal.org/project/field_placeholder)
module.

> Field Placeholder module gives support to add HTML5 placeholder
>   attribute to field widget forms.
>
> By default, this module integrates text, number and mail modules, but
>   any other widget type can be added through
>   hook_field_placeholder_info().
>
> Field placeholder adds a new option in field settings page to enter
>   the placeholder value, which is included automatically when the widget
>   is rendered.